# Move windows between monitors in task view?

Tags: windows-10

When I try to move a window between monitors in Windows 10 Task View, the window gets stuck on the border of the monitor.

[This is a video of what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOfDxvNCMQ4)

This is my monitor screen setup:

[image]

Comment: You video doesn't work in Win7 Media Player and I'm not chasing down codecs for just this video. :)  Please upload it to a video hosting service like YouTube or Vimeo (or alike) and post a link to that.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I copied the wrong link. I updated the post.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your monitor configuration?

Comment: @ElTurner https://i.imgur.com/rtheKBG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your YouTube video doesn't work anymore but I assume you're trying to drag an application window from the Task View on one monitor to another using the mouse.

At the time of writing this answer, Windows 10 Task View doesn't allow you to drag an application window across monitors; it only allows you to drag to a different virtual desktop on the same monitor.  If you try and drag off the monitor, the mouse pointer will move to the other monitor but the thumbnail of the application window you are dragging will disappear as you move to the different monitor.

To back this up you can right-click on the application Window to see the available options.  Here's a picture of me right-clicking my Chrome window and looking at my available options; my only options presented are to move it to a virtual desktop on the current monitor.

[image: picture of right-click menu within Task View on Windows 10]

To move an application window to a different monitor you have to exit task view and return to desktop view.  Options include dragging the application by the title bar to a different window or using the `CTRL + SHIFT + LEFT` AND `CTRL + SHIFT + RIGHT` hotkeys.

Once the application window is on the desired monitor, then you can use Task View to move it to a different desktop.  I agree it would be much better if Task View supported this combined operation directly but currently it doesn't seem to allow that.